# Safari loading very slowly - high load latency

Tags: image, safari, resources, load, latency

I'm working on a web app that allows users to create their own designs, and this app provides the user with a library of images to use in their design. These designs have two images, one low-res image used for the GUI and a high-res one used in the design.

It appears that Chrome/Firefox/IE only load the small thumbnails on page load, and load the larger ones on clicking the thumbnails. On Safari it loads every single image at once which has a huge impact on the page load times. Load time ranges between 5 to 30 seconds on Safari compared to 1 to 2 seconds on other browsers.

```
Safari debugger:  
Total resources: 283   
Resource size: 277 MB  
Load time: 29.78s
```

This is Safari 7.0.5 running on OSX 10.9.4 and also impacts Safari 5.1.7 running on Windows 7.